# Assymmetric top with time-varying moment of inertia

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

Studying the stability of a free asymmetric top is an usual excersice done when one is learning the rigid body motion. One learns that a body will rotate stably about the axis with the largest or the smallest moment of inertia, but not about the intermediate axis.

In such excercise it is considered that $I_1\neq I_2\neq I_3$ are constants. But **what would happen if one of those moment of inertia is varying in time?** Say, a top with moments $I_1(t)>I_2>I_3$, where $I_{2}$ and $I_3$ are constants.

---

I tried solving Euler's equations of motion considering that the top spins about one of the axis, but obtained coupled equations for the angular velocity components, and don't know how to solve them. Because of this, I can't know how the stability of the rigid body would be in this case.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Are you asking us to solve the problem for you? ... Reducing the physical problem to differential equations is physics. Are you asking about that? If you are asking how you can solve the equations you have derived, that is (probably) a mathematical question which might be better on Mathematics SE - unless you wish to make some approximations. There must be software online which you can use to solve the equations numerically.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I want to know how the physical situation would look like, no matter if one needs to solve differential equations or not, maybe some idea given by physical intuition. I have no intuition on this and I can't describe the system mathematically, so I can't know anything about how the stability of this kind of problem would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the question "what would be the effect of a time-varying moment of inertia on stability?" can only be answered definitively by defining the function $I_1(t)$ and examining the equations. It would not be necessary to solve the equations, just examine critical cases.

My own intuition is that if $I_1(t)$ is periodic with a frequency much different from the rotation rate of the body, it is likely to remain stable even for large amplitude (provided that $I_1 \gt I_2$. Whereas if the frequency of $I_1$ is close to the rotation rate of the body then it is likely to become unstable even for small values of amplitude. But this needs to be verified by looking at the equation of motion.